# Mon Dieu! It's civil (servant) war!

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, anagram

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions - place one tile in each region so that the tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged into an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution

> [image]

French MP?

> GENDARME (French Military Policeman)

Bureaucrat

> MANDARIN

Weaponry

> ARMAMENT

Comment: Damn, lost by 50 seconds :<